# Bootstrap - Datetimepicker have big gap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap class datetimepicker and have incredibly big gap on monday numbers:

HTML:
`html <input id="dateFrom" type="text" class="form-control datetimepickerDate cursorPointer" placeholder="@Localizer["Date from"]" readonly />`

jQuery code:

```js
   $(".datetimepickerDate").datetimepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: app.format.date.replace('MM', 'mm'),
    startView: 2,
    maxView: 4,
    minView: 2,
    fontAwesome: true
});
```

End result:
This what is look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGItj.png

How to fix this gap?

Comment: seems some other CSS overwrite.